# Disable inline edit in ui listing

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, uicomponent, list-view, inline-editor

I have created a custom module where i add data. This data is displayed on the grid. On the grid i have enable inline editing.

Now i want to disable this inline editing only when certain condition is match.

Like the parameter passed on the page is x then show the inline edit else disable inline edit.

Comment: did you find any solution??

Comment: No. I had to create different controller, as i had less time for RND.

Answer (score 3):

For Example:
if you want to disable inline edit

app/code/Custom/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/customer_listing.xml

```
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
   <columns name="customer_columns">
        <settings>
            <editorConfig>
            <param name="enabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</param>

</editorConfig>
</settings>
</columns>
</listing>
```

This following piece of code should disable the inline editing feature.

Comment: Element 'editorConfig': This element is not expected.

Comment: what version of magento you are using..?

Comment: 2.2.6 version of Magento

Answer (score 0):

In case someone stumble upon this issue.
For Magento 2.3.7 you should have something like that in your layout

```
<item name="editorConfig" xsi:type="array">
        ...
        <item name="enabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
        ...
</item>
```

Just change it to 'false' and clear cache